# A bijection from a compact interval to itself to turn a non-monotonic function into a monotonic one.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functions

Suppose that $f \in C[a,b]$, $a, b \in \mathbb R$ is some, possibly non-monotonic, function. I want to claim that there exists a bijection $h:[a,b] \to [a,b]$ such that the map $g : = f(h):[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ given by $x \mapsto f(h(x))$ is monotonic in $x$.

If the domain was finite, this is obvious. If it was countable it seems to not be true. For example, take a sequence $x_n = (-1)^n \frac1n$. That is, the map here is $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ given by $n \mapsto x_n$. Does compactness of $[a,b]$ and continuity of $f$ help in the above claim being true? As pointed out below, maybe I need $f$ to be of bounded variation. So, can one construct such an $h$ if $f$ had bounded variation?

Comment: I think you will need some sort of bounded variation for all derivatives of $f$ for the existence of $h$. I might be wrong, but this statement must also be true for $f(x):=x\cdot \sin(\exp(\frac{1}{x}))$ which is both decaying (and hence continuous) and rapidly oscillating as $x\rightarrow 0$.
The point where I think it will fail is the 'task' of $h$ when it has to sort the regimes where $f$ alternately increases and deacreases at $x=0$.

Comment: thanks. you are probably right. maybe i should add bounded variations too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function

$$f:[0,1]\to[0,1]:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
2x,&\text{if }0\le x\le\frac12\\
2-2x,&\text{if }\frac12\le x\le 1\;;
\end{cases}$$

clearly $f(x)=f(1-x)$ for each $x\in[0,1]$. Let $h:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be any bijection. Fix $x\in\left[0,\frac12\right)$, and let $x_1=h^{-1}(x)$ and $x_2=h^{-1}(1-x)$. Then

$$(f\circ h)(x_1)=f\big(h(x_1)\big)=f(x)=f(1-x)=f\big(h(x_2)\big)=(f\circ h)(x_2)\;.$$

There must be some $y$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$, and clearly $h(x_1)\ne h(y)\ne h(x_2)$, i.e., $x\ne h(y)\ne 1-x$, so $(f\circ h)(y)=f\big(h(y)\big)\ne f(x)$, and $f\circ h$ is not monotone.

Comment: Thanks. This is great.

Comment: @avk255: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is not monotonic, then we can find points $p<r<q$ such that $f(p)=f(q) \neq f(r)$. But if $h(f)$ is monotonic, $h(f(p))=h(f(q))$ implies $h(f(q)) = h(f(r))$, and so $h$ cannot be injective.

Comment: You are right. There was a big, and important, mistake in the question. I have edited it now. Thanks.